# Parse String without removing the token

Tags: java, regex, parsing, delimiter

I have a string to parse in java. My input string is :  `#hello#adam@how@are@you`.
I expect the output to be:

```
#hello

#adam

@how

@are

@you
```

I have tried with the following code but it is not giving the desired output.

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(txt,"#,");
    ArrayList<String> str =new ArrayList<String>();
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        str.add(st.nextElement().toString());
    }
```

Comment: This is a (rough) sketch of a requirement -- it's not a question. If the question is "how do I do it," that's too broad for SO. You should give this a try, and if in doing so you come up with a _specific_ question (how do I do this one step, or "I did X and expected A but saw B"), you can ask that question (assuming you first search to make sure it hasn't already been answered, of course).

Comment: Have you tried some code ? Give us that... then may be we can help.

Comment: So, now you have a rough sketch of the requirement, some sample input, and a bit of code that is "not giving the desired output". What output is it giving instead? (Hint: it's not giving any output, because you don't output anything.) What are the values of things in intermediate steps? If you narrow down the question, it will not only help us answer it -- it may help you answer it without our help. For instance, how many times does the loop happen? What are `str`'s values? What would you want them to be, and how can you get them there? (hint: look at `returnDelims` in StringTokenizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this with a regular expression.

Considering only the information you provided, this might be a possible solution.

```
public class Parsing {
    public static void main (final String[] args) {

        final String regexp = "([@#][a-z]+)";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
        final String input = "#hello#adam@how@are@you";

        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```